# What is the easiest way to set custom binary data messages in Java?

Tags: java, binary, byte, bit

Coming from the world of C# and brushing up on Java, I have learned that there are no unsigned bytes/ints.  I am trying to find out what is the easiest way build up custom binary messages such as the following example:

[image]

As you can see, certain integer values need to put into a 3 bit slot.  others values are single bit flags, or other size fields.  From what I have read, I should work in the "next larger" primitive, such as building binary bytes in integers using bit wise operators.  Are there other ways? I have followed some examples I found elsewhere such as (Note: this example does not match the graphic above) to get the first byte structured:

```
shiftedValue1 = (value1 & 0xFF) << 5;
shiftedValue2 = (Value2 & 0xFF) << 2;
shiftedValue3 = (Value3 & 0xFF) << 1;
shiftedValue4 = (Value4 & 0xFF);
finalvalue = (shiftedValue1 & 0xFF) | (shiftedValue2 & 0xFF) | (shiftedValue3 & 0xFF) | (shiftedValue4 & 0xFF);
```

Is there a better way to construct these bytes?  What do I use on 4 Byte fields? Longs?

Comment: Maybe I'm being clueless, but -- despite the tradition of viewing such fields as unsigned values, is there any actual problem with treating them as signed values? If, in C#, you'd view a given one-byte field as ranging from 0 (`00`) to 255 (`FF`), is there any harm in having it range from 0 to 127 (`00` to `7F`) and -128 to -1 (`80` to `FF`)? Where I work, some of our partners/customers do exactly this; a value that appears in a C enum as `0x85` will appear in an XML attribute as `"-123"`. It sounds a bit odd, but it's never caused any problems.

Comment: I might actually try going in that direction...

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) as described e.g. [here](http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=java.byteBuffer). It should make it easier to manipulate the byte array, especially taking things like endianess into account.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this would be easier to do using either `byte[]` (byte arrays) or [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)s.

Comment: I was originally looking into using a byte[] but from what I understand, the byte in a byte array is still signed, and this requires a bit of "manipulation to work.