# Java class for getting / setting specific bits in a bytearray

Tags: java, byte, arrays

I am looking for a helper class which can modify specific bits in a bytearray, with an API similar to the below:

```
void Set(int startPos, int lengthInBits, int value) {
  // Set the bits starting at startPos to the binary representation of value
  // Error if the binary representation of value is too long (ie. exceeds lengthInBits)
}
```

The purpose is to be able to put specific values of arbitrary length into a bytearray - some values will have length of less than a byte, others more, and some will 'straddle' bytes.

I have looked at [ByteBuffer](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) but this seems slightly too high-level, only working with putting whole bytes, and converting ints and shorts to multiple bytes rather than letting you choose their max number of bits.

I also looked at [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) but this time it seems slightly too low-level, as it only works at the single bit level (although I could potentially use this as a start point for building something with the above sort of API).

There's also an old [somewhat similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793200/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-set-custom-binary-data-messages-in-java) on Stack Overflow, mainly pertaining to the use of signed / unsigned bits, but the data structure pictured is the kind of thing I would be trying to build (a message to send to an external client), and I'd like to hide away as much of the bit-shifting complexity as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not that hard. Maybe this can help you as a starting point:

```
ByteBuffer data;

int getBits(int bitOff, int bitSize)
{
  if(bitSize>32) throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  final int mask= bitSize==32? -1: (1<<bitSize)-1;
  return (int)((data.getLong(bitOff>>>3) >>> (64-bitSize-(bitOff&7))) & mask);
}
void putBits(int bitOff, int bitSize, int intValue)
{
  final int byteOff=bitOff>>>3;
  bitOff -= byteOff<<3;
  final int shift = 64-bitSize-bitOff;
  long mask=Long.rotateLeft((-1L)<<bitSize, shift), lValue=intValue&0xffffffffL;
  data.putLong(byteOff, (lValue << shift) | (data.getLong(byteOff)&mask));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, ideally I'm looking for an existing class / lib that provides such functionality so I don't need to create a custom class & tests for something which I imagine is a pretty common problem. Maybe there isn't anything out there though...

Answer (score 0):

You can extend java.util.BitSet, it already handles storage of an arbitrary number of bits. All you need to add are the bulk get/set operations:

```
public class BulkBitSet extends BitSet {

    public void bulkSet(int offset, int count, int data) {
        int ptr = offset + count;
        for (int i=0; i<count; ++i) {
            set(--ptr, (data & (1 << i)) == 0 ? false : true);
        }
    }

    public int bulkGet(int offset, int count) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<count; ++i) {
            result <<= 1;
            if (get(offset + i))
                result |= 1;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```